# Google Spreadsheet CHECKSTRING(url ; string) (new function needed)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I’m really new to programming so first of all I beg your pardon for my my questions.

I would like to create a function to search the webpage of a site in order to find any string is present.

This function could be written like this. Thanks in advance for your precious help. Then How I can activate it to use it in a cell.

Thanks for your precious help.

Seb

--
**CHECKSTRING(url ; string)**

•   url - The URL of the web page to examine, including protocol (e.g. http:// or https://). 
The value for url must either be enclosed in quotation marks or be a reference to a cell containing the appropriate text.

•   String – The STRING to find in the page source from the URL. The value for String must either be enclosed in quotation marks or be a reference to a cell containing the appropriate text.

This function returns the line number position at which the STRING is first found within URL code source, case-sensitive.

This function returns -1 or FASE when the check answer is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the FINDfunction ?

```
=iferror(find(string_to_search, url), false)
```

or, depending on your locale:

```
=iferror(find(string_to_search; url); false)
```

where string or URL can be passed in as string, or as cell references.

NOTE: if you want to do a case-insensitve search, replace the FIND() with SEARCH()

Comment: Thanks for your prompt anwser but this will check the URL not the content in the webpage. I will keep it BTW, very usefull.

Comment: Yes. That is what I thought your question was about. Sorry.. my bad. I don't know if that will be possible even with a custom function (GAS). Let's hope someone chimes in with a great idea.. :-)